# wp_kses_post only removes <script> tags, but not their content

Tags: wp-kses

Is there any way to remove the `<script>` tags including their contents?

wp_kses_post seems to only remove the tags, while their content remains visible on the page.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KSES is designed to prevent execution of undesired and potentially dangerous tags, not preventing display of the innerHTML. Blocking the content would require

--1 Either a custom function that used some kind of string manipulation or xmlDOM manipulation to remove content; or

--2 A function that blocked posts that contain the  tag with a message why the post failed and instructions for using HTML codes to render script tag when using it in tutorials rather than as an execution tag.

Number 1 may produce performance issues with its higher overhead. If optimizing performance is an issue or if the site involves heavy posting by multiple users, then #2 is likely a  more feasible solution.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest You to use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to filter the post content:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_strip_scripts');

function my_strip_scripts($content){

    return preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $content);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use on my site to strip images and paragraph tags. I'm assuming this is `the_content`?

```
<?php
ob_start();
the_content();
$old_content = ob_get_clean();
$new_content = strip_tags($old_content, '<insert HTML tags you want kept');
echo $new_content; ?>
```

The `$new_content` line will remove all HTML tags except those tags listed after `$old_content`

Answer (score 0):

Give [wp_strip_all_tags()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_strip_all_tags) a shot. I believe it removes the content of script tags also.

Comment: I want to only remove the `<script>` tags. I had a mistake in my post and the editor removed `<script>` because I didn't properly enclose it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use this function: (from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#86964)

```
function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) {

  preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags);
  $tags = array_unique($tags[1]);
   
  if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) {
    if($invert == FALSE) {
      return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:'. implode('|', $tags) .')\b)(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
    }
    else {
      return preg_replace('@<('. implode('|', $tags) .')\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
    }
  }
  elseif($invert == FALSE) {
    return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
  }
  return $text;
}
```

& after that, if you also want to remove all attributes except few(example: href, title), use wp_kses like this:

```
    $content = wp_kses($content, array(
        'a' => array('href' => true, 'title' => true),
        'div' => array(),
        'p' => array(),
    ));
```